# Android - How to display an expired date and notify the user when this has expired

Tags: android, notifications

I'm currently making an android application to manage job applications via a record system, similar to a contacts app or an address book. On the main screen, the user sees a list of records they have created with an 'add' button in the top right. Usually, the list of records displayed just show the job title, acting as the title of the record (i.e Sales Assistant). 
However, one of the criteria the user inputs when they create a record is the date of their interview.

I wanted to make it so that rather than just displaying the job title, the list of records also displays the expiry date. Simple enough, only that this requires the user's inputted date, and the current date registered on the device itself. I don't know how to retrieve these, or how to display the user's date when it has expired, in addition to popping up on the device as a notification.

I also use SQLite to store the various information input by the user when making a record, and use Eclipse to create my app.

in the XML: 
    `

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/interviewDateTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_9dp"
        android:text="@string/interview_date"
        android:textSize="@dimen/padding_9dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/InterviewDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_9dp" >
    </EditText>
</TableRow>`
```

in the SQL query,

`"CREATE TABLE records ( recordId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, jobTitle TEXT, " +
        "jobDescription TEXT, contactNumber TEXT, emailAddress TEXT, contactName TEXT, applicationDate DATE, interview TEXT, " +
        "interviewDate DATE, methodApplied TEXT, companyName TEXT)"`

in the relevant .java files,

```
public void addNewRecord(View view) {

    // Will hold the HashMap of values 

    HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap =  new  HashMap<String, String>();

    // Get the values from the EditText boxes

    queryValuesMap.put("jobTitle", jobTitle.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("jobDescription", jobDescription.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("contactName", contactName.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("emailAddress", emailAddress.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("contactNumber", contactNumber.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("methodApplied", methodApplied.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("interview", interview.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("interviewDate", interviewDate.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("companyName", companyName.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("applicationDate", applicationDate.getText().toString());
    // Call for the HashMap to be added to the database

    dbTools.insertRecord(queryValuesMap);

    this.callMainActivity(view);
}
```

I basically need to compare dates; if the current date is equal to the user's date of interview for any record, then I want to call a notification which will inform them that the interview is today for that record (i.e 'Alert: You have a job interview today for [jobTitle]'). I can create the notification and so forth, it's just fetching and comparing the dates i'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current time, use:

```
long curTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

what format does the user enter the interview date in?